# Would the loss of the ability to become intoxicated deplete cartels of their income?

Tags: crime

This is the third follow up of my question [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/225686/will-people-keep-drinking-alcoholic-drinks-even-if-they-dont-get-intoxicated-an). To review some context, here is what happens :

- a handwavium virus kill off humanity's ability to get intoxicated or high.
- many people experience drug withdrawal at the same time which creates a health crisis.
- the virus however doesn't kill off people's ability to enjoying what they do or consume.
- this virus only impacts the "external" means of becoming intoxicated.

**Question** :

Would this create a great enough financial loss to cartels and organized crime that they would collaborate to attempt to sabotage the government ?

Comment: i feel like you kinda underestimate how wide reaching this would be, throw in pretty much every food or drink company that primarily produces sweet things in there (sugar is actually classified as a drug, its just near completely unregulated compared to others) & you've got a more complete picture, as well as this all alcohol & cigarette companies will be shitting themselves over this

Comment: this event does not make people loss the ability to enjoy what they consume, only the ability to be intoxicated ( that's why this is a handwavium).

Comment: A [cartel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartel) is any group of supposedly independent business which collude to divide the market or to set prices. While all cartels are illegal (in most places), only a small fraction of them are criminal. That's why you always need to specify what kind of cartel you have in mind, such as, for example, a [*drug* cartel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drug_cartel).

Comment: By "ability to enjoying" you mean enjoying through primary senses (taste, smell etc.) rather than physiological effects?

Comment: Also, would legitimate anesthetics like morphine and nitrous oxide lose their effectiveness?

Comment: Well I did cover some economic effects of this change in my answer, which is #3 in your previous topic. I think the answer here also would be Yes, they'll sustain losses! Not sure of the consequences though..

Answer (score 5):

No. Cartels and organized crime tend to move into other sectors of illicit income when forced to do so (such as the repeal of Prohibition).

For instance, there is always human trafficking (pimping and prostitution, traditionally, but also quasi-slavery for labor) and gambling. Occasionally they will shift to protection rackets and graft, though those tend to be less lucrative.

Additionally, many drug cartels do experiment with drugs in the sense that they're looking for new products. Designer drugs, newly discovered phytopharmaceuticals, even drugs that the west are unfamiliar with (khat, etc). If some phenomenon caused people to be unable to "get high" with traditional drugs, it wouldn't be long before they had viable substitutes. A year maybe, or three, but not decades.

Answer (score 1):

**Sabotaging the government is not profitable.**

Sabotaging the government -- I presume you mean something along the lines of blowing up the senate -- is not profitable.

It is more profitable to put cartel people in positions of power, so they can turn a blind eye to your illegal activities. That way you turn the government's power into your power. In particular you can use the police to get rid of rival gangs.

If you destroy the government you destroy yourself. You also destroy any stability that allowed your crime to be successful.

With no government the country is anarchy. There is less demand for drugs and prostitutes and illegal gambling. People are too busy getting the essentials like food and safety to worry about those expensive commodities.

The people are not afraid of your goons anymore. At least not especially. People can only be threatened if they felt safe to begin with. But now they are constantly afraid that each and every one of their neighbors will attack them and take their food. So the goons don't have as much of an impact as before.

It is also easier for smaller unorganized criminals to get your business, since you no longer control the police. This hurts the bottom line.

You can of course start a food racket, but this will be less profitable than the drugs, prostitution, and gambling racket ever was.

You can read about the Yakuza sending huge amounts of humanitarian aid, in response to natural disasters in Japan. Regardless of their intention, or even the truth of these stories, I think we can agree it is in the interest of organized crime that people rebuild as soon as possibly.

There is also the issue that the people outnumber you. If you put too much pressure on them -- for example by putting all the tins of beans in the country in a big castle and declaring the price of beans is now $100 and stealing beans is a capital offense -- then you will end up in a bloodbath, where your castle is seiged by thousands of thousands of civilians. Half of them get mowed down by your automatic weaponry and the other half beat you to death with rocks.

In conclusion, blowing up the senate is a bad idea. And even if your main revenue suddenly disappears by magic, it is still not a good idea to blow up the senate.

Comment: And attempting to overthrow a government is a very risky business. It is always more profitable to find the right prosecutor, judge, governor, etc. to bribe so that investigations get dropped, the lead prosecutor decides not to prosecute "airtight" cases. or the person in jail who has incriminating evidence against you "commits suicide".

Comment: @DavidR Very risky indeed! And it's not like the sudden nationwide withdrawal would makes it any easier either.

Answer (score 0):

**Addiction**

When there is intoxication, people get addicted. So they want more and more of that drug. If somebody doesn't have money to buy the drug, he steals, robs even if he has to kill.

**Finance**

When there is no intoxication, people will not get addicted. They will enjoy if they have enough money otherwise they will just wish.

How many people consume Saffron, Caviar, White Truffle, Wagyu beef etc? Only those who can afford.

**Harmful effects**

Even if a drug is cheap enough, many people will not consume it because of its harmful effects.

**Occlusion**

The consumption of drug will reduce a lot and people involved in drug business will have a great financial loss.